# How to send and receive datagram packets continuously from single socket.

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

I want to send and receive datagrampacket from same port. Same socket should be used to send packets and receive packets. If i send it then it can not receive incoming packets at the same time. How to synch send and receive packets from single port?

Comment: Are you meaning UDP datagrams?

Comment: Yes UDP datagram. I want to send and receive voip packets simultaneously from single port.

Comment: Use two threads, one for send, one for receive.  No synch required.

Comment: I am getting Socket Already in Use error if i use same socket in send and receive. Let me try this with single socket connection. Thanks

Comment: you are implementing a complex networking system. Use at least two ports in different threads. If you want to reuse them, remember the .close method

Comment: @kaushikparmar - use the same handle/fd in both threads.  Should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as the following:

```
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);             
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];             
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024]; 

    //receiving:
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

    InetAddress callerIPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();                   
    int callerPort = receivePacket.getPort();

    //sending:  
    sendData = "ciao".getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket =  new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, callerIPAddress, callerPort);
    serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

Comment: thanks robermann. In my case, i am sending single packet and and receiving multiple UDP packets from server. Do i have to use multiple ServerSocket.receive(receivePacket) method? If i would do that then it takes time due to timeout and not able to send packet since receive packet is using socket.

Comment: yes you should use multiple ServerSocket.receive(receivePacket) invocations, probably inside a while. Of course it is a blocking action, you cannot in the same time write a buffer and wait for an input.